# Trying to fork a process in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am reading bash scripting and trying a simple fork scenario where script will fork a process and then the child will perform exec statement

Script is as below

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I am parent process"
echo "my pid is $$"
pid=fork()
if [ $pid eq 0 ]; then
        echo "parent process resumed"
else
        echo "child process pid is $pid"
        exec ls -l
fi
```

It is not working. Does linux bash does not support `fork` like this?

Updated: Editing the output

```
I am parent process
my pid is 61978
new_child_process: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
new_child_process: line 4: `pid=fork()'
```

Comment: `bash` doesn't have a `fork` statement/command. Use `&` to get background processes.

Comment: wondering if OP ran `man fork` and got the man page for the `awk` extension?

Comment: @markp or the C system call...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fork` is not directly available in bash, but it can be [effectively simulated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7609/79839) with `&`.

A couple of other things about this code:

- To do a numeric comparison you should use `-eq` not `eq` (note the extra dash `-`).
- It is also considered a best practice to use `[[ ]]` for tests instead of `[ ]`.

Comment: I added output in the question now.

Comment: Thanks.  That helped me realize what the real problem was.  My first round of googling misled me that `fork` existed in bash.

Comment: In general, `fork` is a low-level operation that you shouldn't have to worry about at the level of shell scripts. It's something that bash does internally (every time you run a non-builtin command, it does a `fork()` to create a new copy of itself followed by an `exec()` to replace that new copy with whatever command you asked it to run). While `exec` has uses at the shell-level to avoid cluttering up the process table,the things you would use a `fork` for are generally better done using jobs.